# JSON Schema 'Required' validation set/removed by checkbox

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I am designing a web application modelled using JSON Schema. I am attempting to create a page with a text area and a checkbox. The text area is to explain why I like pizza. If the user clicks the check box, they are confirming they don't like pizza. The text box is 'required' unless the checkbox is selected. The checkbox is effectively operating as a boolean, but the components being used cannot be altered (because a user researcher said so). At the moment, I'm using AJV to validate my schema, and it is configured to throw `errorMessages.required` when a property is `required` but no input is entered/selected.

Unfortunately I'm completely inexperienced when it comes to JSON schema. Below is my current attempt to get this to validate. This renders correctly, but it doesn't work as I want - In my dev environment it just validates anything, yet on [jsonschemavalidator.net](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) it wont validate unless the checkbox is checked. How can my desired function be achieved?

```
{
$schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
type: 'object',
additionalProperties: false,
propertyNames: {
    enum: [
        'q-why-i-love-pizza',
        'q-i-hate-pizza'
    ]
},
properties: {
    'q-why-i-love-pizza': {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'If you love pizza, tell us why',
        maxLength: 500,
        errorMessages: {
            required: "Please tell us why you love pizza, or select 'I hate pizza'"
        }
    },
    'q-i-hate-pizza': {
        type: 'array',
        maxItems: 1,
        uniqueItems: true,
        items: {
            anyOf: [
                {
                    title: 'I hate pizza',
                    const: 'hate'
                }
            ]
        },
        errorMessages: {
            required: "Please tell us why you love pizza, or select 'I hate pizza'"
        }
    }
},
allOf: [
    {
        $ref: '#/definitions/if-not-checked-then-q-why-i-love-pizza-is-required'
    }
],
definitions: {
    'if-not-checked-then-q-why-i-love-pizza-is-required': {
        if: {
            not: {
                properties: {
                    'q-i-hate-pizza': {
                        const: 'hate'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        then: {
            required: ['q-why-i-love-pizza'],
            propertyNames: {
                enum: [
                    'q-i-hate-pizza',
                    'q-why-i-love-pizza'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

I expect the following:

```
{
    'q-why-i-love-pizza' : '',
    'q-i-hate-pizza' : ['']
}
```

This should FAIL validation as no values have been selected.

```
{
    'q-why-i-love-pizza' : 'I love pizza because it's amazing',
    'q-i-hate-pizza' : ['']
}
```

This should PASS because the user has entered why they love pizza, so clicking the check box was not necessary.

```
{
    'q-why-i-love-pizza' : '',
    'q-i-hate-pizza' : ['hate']
}
```

This should PASS because although the user has not told us why they love pizza, they have checked the box to indicate they hate pizza.

```
{
    'q-why-i-love-pizza' : 'I am a user, so decided to tell you I hate pizza too',
    'q-i-hate-pizza' : ['hate']
}
```

This should also PASS because I need to accept the possibility that a user will tick the box to say they hate Pizza, but proceed to tell me anyway.

***Solution***:

```
{
    type: "object",
    properties: {    
        'q-why-i-love-pizza': {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'If you love pizza, tell us why',
            maxLength: 500,
            errorMessages: {
            required: "Please tell us why you love pizza, or select 'I hate pizza'"
            }
        },
        'q-i-hate-pizza': {
            type: 'array',
            maxItems: 1,
            uniqueItems: true,
            items: {
                anyOf: [
                    {
                        title: 'I hate pizza',
                        const: 'hate'
                    }
                ]    
            },
            errorMessages: {
                required: "Please tell us why you love pizza, or select 'I hate pizza'"
            }
        }
    },
    allOf: [
        { $ref: "#/definitions/if-not-checked-then-q-offender-contact-description-is-required" }
    ],
    definitions: {
        "if-not-checked-then-q-offender-contact-description-is-required": {
            if: {
                not: {
                    required: ["q-i-hate-pizza"]
                }
            },
            then: {
                required: ["q-why-i-love-pizza"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your schema, so this might not be perfect, but this general approach should work.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "q-why-i-love-pizza": { "type": "string", "maxLength": 500 },
    "q-i-hate-pizza": { "const": ["hate"] }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/if-hates-pizza-then-q-why-i-love-pizza-is-required" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "if-hates-pizza-then-q-why-i-love-pizza-is-required": {
      "if": { "not": { "required": ["q-i-hate-pizza"] } },
      "then": { "required": ["q-why-i-love-pizza"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to revert your changes to my "properties" for the sake of my renderer, but your if/then part appears to have done the trick! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way there, but you've missed something you may not have expected.

Your schema for `if-not-checked-then-q-why-i-love-pizza-is-required`.
The `const` keyword is only applicable to the property, IF it exists.
You need to add a `required` constraint to the `if` schema.

Obviously this is at a guess, as you haven't provided your JSON instance data.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide expected pass and fail JSON instance data.

Comment: Thank you, that has improved my situation. However, it's still not quite right. It will now only validate if both the checkbox is checked and the user enters a value in the text area. I have edited my question to include what I want to pass and fail

Comment: OK, so if you make `q-i-hate-pizza` in your `if` block, then all work as expected apart from the second instance, which should pass, but fails.

Comment: I think it would be easier to create this construct using `oneOf`, which is actually semantically closer to what you want according to your question. It should be easier to understand too. I'm unlikely to have time today to create this, but I'd say have a go and see if you can figure it out. I might have time to help later or tomorrow.